# Setting up executable jar file with multiple classes for putting on website

Tags: java, eclipse, jar, executable-jar, japplet

I use Eclipse IDE and wants to build a jar file for my java applet.

So I go to export...Runnable JAR file...Extract required libraries into generated JAR.

Since I have three classes in the applet, I am not quite sure what should I put in the main-class in manifest. I just choose the class that runs most of the parts of the program as the main class.

But when I put on the website, I got NoClassDefFoundError. So I guess there must be something else going on to deal with more than one class. Can anyone tell me the right procedure to create the jar file and how to edit the manifest with multiple classes that are able to be posted on a website please? Thanks!

Comment: *"But when I put on the website,.."*  What web site?  Where can we visit it?

Comment: Please post the full stack trace of the NoClassDefFoundError, and please post the HTML fragment (<applet>, <object>, etc.) which refers to the applet.